# How can I tell if a certain package was already installed?

Tags: r, rstudio

When I install the yaml package, an annoying error message pops up in RStudio if it had been previously installed. How can I tell if the package was already installed so I can decide in my code whether to install the package or not?

The message is in a pop up window and it is:

> One or more of the packages that will be updated by this installation
>   are currently loaded. Restarting R prior to updating these packages is
>   strongly recommended. RStudio can restart R and then automatically
>   continue the installation after restarting (all work and data will be
>   preserved during the restart). Do you want to restart R prior to
>   installing?

Comment: ... Why are you trying to install it repeatedly? The command to load an installed package is `library(foo)`. Are you running `install.packages` by mistake?

Comment: Not reproducible. I get no error message. (I do get an informational message telling me that it was installed.) Ah. It's an RStudio informational message, not a message from R.

Comment: I'm writing code that will be run on computers that have never used R before. So the code needs to have install.packages("yaml") first. I'm concerned that if a user runs the code twice in a row for some reason, then the message will pop up and they will be confused.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will load `yaml`, installing it first if its not already installed:

```
if (!require(yaml)) {
  install.packages("yaml")
  library(yaml)
}
```

or if you want to parameterize it:

```
pkg <- "yaml"
if (!require(pkg, character.only = TRUE)) {
  install.packages(pkg)
  if (!require(pkg, character.only = TRUE)) stop("load failure: ", pkg)
}
```

UPDATE.  Parametrization.

Comment: Much better than my `tryCatch` hack. Will adopt.

Answer (score 10):

you can use `installed.packages()` to find installed packages

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use the `require` function. It will try to load the package and silently return a logical stating whether or not the package is available. There is also a warning if the package cannot be loaded.

```
test1 <- require("stats")
test1

test2 <- require("blah")
test2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following construction in my code. The essential part is about calling `library` within `tryCatch` and installing it if it fails:

```
lib.auto <- function(lib, version=NULL, install.fun=install.packages, ...) {
  tryCatch(
    library(lib, character.only=T),
    error=function(e) {
      install.fun(lib, ...)
      library(lib, character.only=T)
    }
  )
  if (!is.null(version)) {
    if (packageVersion(lib) < version) {
      require(devtools)
      detach(paste0('package:', lib), unload=T, character.only=T)
      install.fun(lib, ...)
      library(lib, character.only=T)
      if (packageVersion(lib) < version) {
        stop(sprintf('Package %s not available in version %s. Installed version: %s', lib, version,
                     packageVersion(lib)))
      }
    }
  }
}

lib.auto('BiocInstaller',
         install.fun=function(lib) {
           source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
           biocLite(lib)
         })

options(repos=biocinstallRepos())
lib.auto.bioc <- lib.auto

lib.auto.github <- function(lib, version=NULL, user, subdir=NULL, repo=lib)
  lib.auto(lib, version=version,
           install.fun=function(l, u, s, r) {
             require(devtools)
             install_github(r, u, subdir=s)
           },
           user, subdir, repo           
  )
```

The `lib.auto` function installs from CRAN and Bioconductor, if required. The `lib.auto.github` installs from GitHub.

I am thinking about pushing this code into a package.