# Define function / global variable only if first run

Tags: r, global-variables, user-defined-functions

*This seems like something that would have been asked before, yet I can't find it.*

I have an R file which starts with the code for defining functions as global variables and loading libraries. Lots of them. I would like to have those run only if they have not run before.

For libraries, the following code (found here: [How can I tell if a certain package was already installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683387/how-can-i-tell-if-a-certain-package-was-already-installed)) does the job:

```
if (!require(rockchalk)) {library(rockchalk)}
```

Is there anything similar for defining global variables? As an example, I would like the following code to only run once (rather than every time I rerun the whole file):

```
rowShift <- function(x, shiftLen = 1L) { 
  r <- (1L + shiftLen):(length(x) + shiftLen)
  r[r<1] <- NA
  return(x[r])  
}
```

Comment: A combination of `<<-` and `exists` perhaps.

Comment: It might be easier for some people to suggest a solution if we had a clearer picture of why you would want to do something like this in the first place.

Comment: `if (!require(rockchalk)) library(rockchalk)` is a pointless line. `require()` will try to load the package, (using more or less the same method as `library()`), so this is really just saying "try to load with require, if that doesn't work, try to load with library". I don't know of any situation where a load with `require` would fail but a load with `library()` would succeed. You're better off just keeping it clear and simple with `library(rockchaclk)`. It's smart enough not to re-attach the package if already attached.

Comment: The `if (require(...))` idiom is only useful if you put an `install.packages()` to attempt to download a missing package if the `require()` is unsuccessful, as is done in the question you link.

Comment: @joran: rerunning something that has not changed is inefficient. Excluding the code manually from running takes more time than not excluding it. There must be a way to say only run if not already defined.

Comment: If your variables are mostly utility functions and constants as in your example, the usual approach would be to put them in a separate file, something like `utilities.r` or `constants.r` and source it separately from your main script.

Comment: Following up on an earlier comment, for your function: `if(!exists(rowShift)) { <load function> or <run utility script>}`.

Comment: If you want to be weird and verbose, @TheComeOnMan's suggestion to use `exists` would work. `if (! exists(x = "rowShift")) {rowShift <- ...}`. But it seems very silly to write this out before every definition. Just put things in a different file.

Comment: Thank you all very much.`if (! exists(x = "rowShift")) {rowShift <- ...}` is what I was looking for, though guess the more elegant answer is placing functions in a different file.

Comment: Defining a function is *very* fast. Don't worry about this. However, you probably should create a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (! exists(x = "rowShift")) {rowShift <- ...}
```